# Row multiplication in R

Tags: r, row, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply two data frames which have equal columns but unequal rows. The idea is to multiply each row in data set B with every row in data set A. 
data set A

```
**Category  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7**
Food        10  15  28  30  60  33  35
Homecare    14  19  32  34  64  37  39
Apparel     17  22  35  37  67  40  42
Personal    30  35  48  50  80  53  55
AlcBever    33  38  51  53  83  56  58
Footwear    40  45  58  60  90  63  65
NonAlcBev   25  30  43  45  75  48  50
```

data set B

```
    **Country   b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6  b7**
USA            0.5  0.3 0.1 0.4 0.7 0.2 0.8
Sweden         0.6  0.4 0.2 0.5 0.8 0.3 0.9
UK             0.4  0.2 0.1 0.3 0.6 0.1 0.7
```

I would like to get three resultant columns( one for each country) where the following calculations are performed at every row (i.e. sumproduct)

a1*b1+a2*b2........+a7*b7

How do I go about this? Do I use loops?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `datasetA %*% t(datasetB)`? (coerce your datasets to matrices before)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use matrix algebra:

```
DF1 <- read.table(text = "Category  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7
Food        10  15  28  30  60  33  35
                  Homecare    14  19  32  34  64  37  39
                  Apparel     17  22  35  37  67  40  42
                  Personal    30  35  48  50  80  53  55
                  AlcBever    33  38  51  53  83  56  58
                  Footwear    40  45  58  60  90  63  65
                  NonAlcBev   25  30  43  45  75  48  50", header = TRUE)

DF2 <- read.table(text = "Country   b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6  b7
USA            0.5  0.3 0.1 0.4 0.7 0.2 0.8
                  Sweden         0.6  0.4 0.2 0.5 0.8 0.3 0.9
                  UK             0.4  0.2 0.1 0.3 0.6 0.1 0.7", header = TRUE)


m1 <- as.matrix(DF1[-1])
rownames(m1) <- DF1[[1]]

m2 <- as.matrix(DF2[-1])
rownames(m2) <- DF2[[1]]

tcrossprod(m1, m2)

#            USA Sweden    UK
#Food      100.9  122.0  82.6
#Homecare  112.9  136.8  92.2
#Apparel   121.9  147.9  99.4
#Personal  160.9  196.0 130.6
#AlcBever  169.9  207.1 137.8
#Footwear  190.9  233.0 154.6
#NonAlcBev 145.9  177.5 118.6
```

Answer (score -2):

How about creating a new dataset with all combinations of the first and second dataframe and then sum the rows?

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by=NULL) %>%
       mutate(sum = rowSums(.[grepl("^[ab]",names(df))])) %>%
       select(-grep("^[ab]",names(df)))
```

Comment: They might run out of memory with a cartesian join.

Comment: However, I don't believe this answer should be downvoted. I think it still can be useful.

Comment: @Roland, this answer is imo not a good alternative to `tcrossprod`, which you already provided. The technique may be useful in another context but for this particular question, of a matrix product, I don't find it helpful to propose an answer that needs another package, is memory greedy and very likely less efficient, that's why I downvoted it.